# Script to compare decimal number with other number

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to get CPU utilization for some of PROD servers and get alerted if it reach on certain value on SunOS servers.

To do so trying below:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
CPU=10
prstat -a 3 1 | awk '{print $1,$2,$9;}' | head -5 > top5.txt
cat top5.txt | awk '{print $3;}' | sed '1d' > re.txt
if [ `cat re.txt` -gt $CPU ];
then
echo "this is TEST"
fi
```

content from top5.txt file:

```
cat test.txt
PID USERNAME CPU
20845 sql 2.5
25690 sql 0.3
986 splunk 0.2
5 root 0.1
```

content from re.txt file:

```
cat re.txt
2.5
0.3
0.2
0.1
```

Getting error:

```
 " [: 0.3%: unknown operator"
```

first two commands are executing and giving expected outcome but while it is going on loop to check condition (>10) then unable to make comparison if value from file "re.txt" is on decimal digit.

Please could someone can tell a way to compare such values reading from file.

Thanks in ADV....

Answer (score 0):

```
prstat -a 3 1|awk -v cpu=10 'NR<=5 && NR!=1 && $3 > cpu{print "This is Test..."}'
```

This is an `awk` solution not exactly pure bash here all conditions are present. Also, note that creating tempory files for your processing is not a very good solution.(like `top5.txt ,re.txt`).

Explanation:

`awk -v cpu=10` : This is assigning a value to an awk variable named `cpu`.
`NR<=5` : This means top 5 lines.
`NR!=1`: Means not the first line.
 `NR<=5 && NR!=1` : this combined means, lines 2 to 5.
`$3>cpu` : This means if third colum is greter then the value of variable `cpu`.

If all aforementioned conditions are meet then execute `{print "this is test"}`

Here is example:

```
echo "$x"
PID USERNAME CPU
20845 sql 2.5
25690 sql 0.3
986 splunk 0.2
5 root 0.1
4 test 11

echo "$x" |awk -v cpu=10 'NR<=6 && NR!=1 && $3 > cpu{print "This is Test... " $0}'
This is Test... 4 test 11
```

Comment: Hi PS, I am not very much expert on scripting. Could you please mind to explain what is and which part of command doing what. Need little help to understand here.

Comment: @Kabir first please let us know if this helped to get the desired results ?

Comment: while putting suggested command to shell and executed getting below error:   cat thread.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
prstat -a 3 1|awk -v cpu=10 'NR<=5 && NR!=1 && $3 > cpu{print "This is Test..."}'      awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: try using `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` insted of just `awk`

Comment: yes it worked, but output ("this is test") came 4 time on screen. As per requirement if cpu utilization is >10% by any of process then only it should print the greater value only. Checked current cpu utilization is for top 5 line and those all are less than 4.

Comment: but what if multiple lines have higher value ? , you can use `{print "this is test";exit}` to print only once

Comment: Yes that is possible to have multiple lines more that 10 but it must print only when cpu value is >10, if it <=10 then there should not be any print

Comment: in that case, current solution will only print if CPU usage is greter then 10 not all the lines, how this is not anwereing your requirement ?

Comment: yes this is the requirement. as I said if any of top 5 lines which we are looking from our command having >10 cpu usage then only it must proceed further else exit. but using this command it is printing or proceeding no matter if value is <10.

Comment: I have added example  in the answer with the output where the CPU usage of `test` is higer then `10`. let me know your expected output from it.

Comment: I need exactly the same output. 4 is SID TEST is user and 11 is cpu utilization. could you please telling me what is $x and $0 in your command. I am using total lines in my shell is:  #!/usr/bin/sh
prstat -a 3 1|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v cpu=10 'NR<=5 && NR!=1 && $3 > cpu{print "This is Test..."}'

Comment: Here `$x` is a variable where I have stored the data for test, `$0` is the whole line, like `$1` is first column , If this answers your query please accept the answer for closure.

Comment: but in my case this is giving output no matter if value is <10. while in your case it didn't picked up those value of CPU which are <11 i.e. 0.1,0.2,0.3 etc